# iframe src is not recognized on php basis

Tags: php, function, iframe, function-pointers

so, i have this iframe that looks like this on the page: **(not recognizing PHP tag)**

```
<iframe class="iframe" src="/message.html?msjId=<? echo $msj_id ?>
```

it's printing from a php function that looks like this :

```
print('msjID, stamp,Name,Status, $table, 'messages','<iframe class="iframe" src="/message.html?msjId=<? echo $msj_id ?>">');
```

the header of this function looks like this :

```
function print($header, &$table, $title='',$iframe) {
```

so the `$table` is an array of the value of `msjID, stamp, Name ,Status`.

MY PROBLEM: the iframe is not recognizing the php tag so i can't get the msjId from the DB with the `foreach` statement.

need help please!

UPDATE:

So let me explain my problem with the foreach: i have this already:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
            $msj_id = $tablerow['msj_id'];
}
 print('msjID, stamp,Name,Status, $table, 'messages','<iframe class="iframe" src="/message.html?msjId=<? echo $msj_id ?>">');
```

if i put the print function in the loop it will print tables like this:

```
|table msj_id=1|


|table msj_id=2|
|table msj_id=2|

|table msj_id=3|
|table msj_id=3|
|table msj_id=3|
```

i need only the last one not all of them, i need only like this:

|table msj_id=1|
|table msj_id=2|
|table msj_id=3|

var_dump inside the loop for msj_id is :

```
string '297-3' (length=5)

string '296-3' (length=5)

string '300-3' (length=5)
```

outside the loop is :

```
 string '300-3' (length=5)
```

Comment: It has to do with how you build your `$result`. Can you show us where it comes from?

Comment: Show us the query. And what is the difference between `$row` and `$tablerow`?

Comment: sorry it's the same my mistake

Comment: OK. Then it has to come from the DB query.

Comment: see my update with the var_dump for that msj_id

Comment: According to your var_dump inside the loop, everything is fine. It looks like it's a problem with how the print function works. Where does it come from?

Comment: @mbinette it comes from a functions file, and it look like in my functions just prints a table like `<table><tbody> ... `

Comment: It looks to me like each time you print it, it prints the table AND the ones it previously printed as it's printing 1 + 2 + 3 tables while your var_dump test shows there is only 3 calls to it. (like using a buffer and not clearing it?!)

Comment: I dnt think so there is anything like function pointer or even pointers in php

Comment: @mbinette acctually yes but i failed again see my update about how it shows the tables ...

Answer (score 2):

Dont use **function print**
Use Different name

```
<?php
function printer($header, &$table, $title='',$iframe) {
echo "'msjID, stamp,Name,Status, $table, 'messages','<iframe class=\"iframe\" src=\"/message.html?msjId=".$msj_id."";
}
?>
```

Use Like This

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as the iframe not recognizing PHP tags... PHP tags are parsed server-side, the iframe works client-side.

The client cannot parse PHP. Try this:

```
foreach($msjID as $value)
    print($value, $table, 'messages','<iframe class="iframe" src="/message.html?msjId='.$msj_id.'">');
```

[image]

By the way, don't use short tags `<? ?>`, use `<?PHP ?>` :-)

Comment: Then give us the generated HTML code.. What does it look like?

Comment: the HTML code looks like `<iframe class="iframe" src="/message.html?msjId=<? echo $msj_id ?>
` i wrote in the question... this is how it looks like in the page source

Comment: the $msj_id is an array, but with your answer is giving me the same 3 iframes for different msj_ids but it's working, how can we get an array like this ?

Comment: don't understand you answer my problem is with the msj_id inside the iframe src because it take one value and my basic msj_id is an array in my case with three ids

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you want. I also read French if you feel you can express yourself better in French. (but see my edit, I tried again)

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you more unless you give me the code (or reference to the code) of your print function and the content of the tables you are doing the query on (and the query itself). I am missing information, because everything else looks fine. However, when I see more information, I might figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your print function will NOT evaluate PHP tags. You need to use PHP variables in that print function like this:

```
foreach ($msj_id as $id) {
    print('msjID, stamp,Name,Status', $table, 'messages','<iframe class="iframe" src="/message.html?msjId='.$id.'">');
}
```

Comment: the $msj_id is an array, but with your answer is giving me the same 3 iframes for different msj_ids but it's working, how can we get an array like this ?

Comment: if it's an array, are you trying to display 3 different iframes?

Comment: yes, this iframe is like a preview of the text message by iframe

Comment: by using foreach, you can print all values of your $msj_id - see the updated answer

Comment: my problem is if i use the print function inside the foreach it will be like this : at first one table , then another printing with two tables and after that another printing with three tables, do you know what i mean? i would like to use it to generate one big table wit the three messages by id...

Comment: in that case it would be vital to share your print() function as well, since as we can't see it, we can't help much

Comment: I do understand the problem, however you seem to be concatenating a string inside your own `print()` function, thus we need to see the `print()` function itself to be able to help you :) ... also, do not use the name **print**, as it's reserved by PHP's built-in [print()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) function

Comment: yes, sure, it's not a problem that it's just a dummy name here... can we talk on the chat, can you invite me to a chat room please so we can talk faster? thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17200/discussion-between-zathrus-writer-and-jimmy)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
print('msjID, stamp,Name,Status, $table, 'messages','<iframe class="iframe" src="/message.html?msjId='.$msj_id.'">');
```

Comment: the $msj_id is an array, but with your answer is giving me the same 3 iframes for different msj_ids but it's working, how can we get an array like this ?

Comment: use loop to iterate over the array,thats easy like foreach($msj_id as $msj_id_instance){print('msjID, stamp,Name,Status, $table, 'messages','<iframe class="iframe" src="/message.html?msjId='.$msj_id_instance.'">');}